# Dirac equation in curved space-time with Torsion

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, resource-recommendations, differential-geometry, dirac-equation

I am looking for pedagogical references in which [Dirac equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation_in_curved_spacetime) in space-time with curvature and torsion were discussed.